# How to specify key in SSHFS?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, sshfs

I've got a question that I've not been able to find an answer for. I have two computers, both of which run Ubuntu Linux 12.04. I have set up my first computer ("home") to be able to SSH into my second computer ("remote") using public/private RSA key authentication.

This is not the first SSH connection that  have set up using key authentication on my home computer, so my home computer has several id_rsa private keyfiles (each of which is for a different computer to SSH into). Thus, I am able to successfully SSH only when I specify a keyfile (in `ssh`, the `-i` option), using `ssh username@ipaddress -i path/to/keyfile/id_rsa.2`.

That works great. However, I would also like to use `sshfs`, which mounts the remote filesystem. While `ssh` seems to play nice with multiple keys, I can't find a way to get `sshfs` to use the correct private key ("id_rsa.2").

Is there a way to get `sshfs` to do this?

Comment: [Keychain](http://www.funtoo.org/wiki/Keychain) works well for me in this scenario...

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Here's what works for me:

```
sshfs me@x.x.x.x:/remote/path /local/path/ -o IdentityFile=/path/to/key
```

You can figure this out via `man sshfs`:

> -o SSHOPT=VAL    ssh options (see man ssh_config)

`man ssh_config`

> IdentityFile
>
> Specifies a file from which the user's DSA, ECDSA or DSA authentication identity is read.

Comment: This command does not work on macOS Sierra

Comment: `IdentityFile` path note. If running `sshfs` with `sudo`, using `~` in the `IdentityFile` path refers to root's home, which may not be where the RSA file is. Use something like `/Users/<username>/.ssh` instead.

Comment: Caveats: `IdentityFile=` must be an absolute path not a relative path. I learned this today.

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks for describing the way how did you figured it out. Reading man files is sometimes a bit tricky for me - I do not read them I just search them and this particular note was not matched by my search at all ;)

Comment: @ino You can use regular expressions in the `man` pager forward slash (/) search (actually the pager is `less` by default). They seem to be PCRE style too (the style used in most modern programming languages); `man less` just says "the regular expression library supplied by your system`.  I use `^\s+-x` a lot, which will find lines starting with some space then `-x`, so good for searching long lists of options.  You can also use `man -H` to format it as html and send it to `$BROWSER` if available, sometimes easier to read.

Answer (score 32):

What you need to do is specify which private key to use in the `~/.ssh/config` file. for example:

```
Host server1.nixcraft.com
    IdentityFile ~/backups/.ssh/id_dsa
Host server2.nixcraft.com
    IdentityFile /backup/home/userName/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Thanks so much! @Steven You, I didn't realize that `sshfs` reads .ssh/config files (though I do see now that I missed a similar answer from someone's previous post, at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13638806/1940466). That's excellent to know.

For what it's worth, I would like to accept both your and @goldilocks' answers, but I'm not able to. I also don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer. I very much appreciate the answer, though!

Answer (score 8):

```
sshfs -o ssh_command='ssh -i path/to/keyfile/id_rsa.2' username@ipaddress:/path /local/path
```

Comment: thanks this answer worked for me on Arch Linux for mounting android file system

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the solution proposed by @Steven You, a simple solution is :

1. go to `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host <nick name>
    HostName  <ipaddress>
    User <username>
    PubKeyAuthentication yes
    IdentityFile <path/to/keyfile/id_rsa.2>
```

2. `sshfs -p 22 <nick name>:source/file/on/server local/folder/`

Answer (score 0):

From a live server.

Type this (with your modifications) in the shell (command line)

sudo sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions,IdentityFile=/home/osmc/.ssh/id_rsa pi@192.168.50.71:/home/pi/torrents/rtorrent /mnt/server/

If you want it to come up during a reboot then edit /etc/fstab

sudo nano /etc/fstab
pi@192.168.50.71:/home/pi/torrents/rtorrent     /mnt/server     fuse.sshfs      delay_connect,rw,nosuid,nodev,default_permissions,allow_other,IdentityFile=/home/osmc/.ssh/id_rsa    0 0

Note the added delay_connect option for the /etc/fstab entry.

Also note that the id_rsa file is generated without a password.

Also note that this mount is first mounted manually to get the ssh fingerprint added to /home/osmc/.ssh/known_host