# scp between two servers not in the same network

Tags: ssh, routing, scp, vlan

There are two server that I can access with 2 different VPN connections. I have managed to have both VPN working on the same time on my machine (a bit of routing rules).

I want to do a `scp <remote1>:some/file <remote2>:destination/folder` from my laptop terminal. But when I try this, the `scp` command that is invoked on *remote1* cannot find *remote2* because they are not in the same network. Is it possible to force the `scp` command to pass through my laptop as a router?

If I try with Nautilus (connect to server, both servers, then copy-paste) it works, but I'd like to do it from a terminal.

Comment: It's your machine that contacts both, _remote1_ and _remote2_. Are you sure the error is that _remote1_ can't access _remote2_?

Comment: Yes, the error is ssh: Could not resolve hostname <remote2>: Name or service not known
lost connection

Comment: And if I try to use the IP address directly for <remote2> the connection fails after a while (hangout).

Comment: Then I guess it's your machine that can't connect to _remote2_. Perhaps the VPN connection times out or is flakey...

Comment: No it works, even the DNS is working. I really have the feeling that the scp command tries to execute the connection between *remote1* and *remote2* directly on *remote1*.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Newer versions of scp have the option -3

> -3
>
> ```
> Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local host. Without this option the data is copied directly between the two remote hosts
> ```

Comment: great! Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot

Comment: Great find, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 10):

If you need more flexibility than `scp -3`, plain `ssh` and pipes are fun.

This is equivalent to redirecting the stream over the local machine:

```
ssh sourceRemote 'cat /path/to/sourceFile' \
| ssh destinationRemote 'cat > /path/to/destinationFile'
```

You can then add more stream redirections at any point, to e.g. chain several intermediate machines, or save a local copy of the transferred file as it's being routed.

Comment: You'll get a nice progress bar if the source machine has `pv` installed and you replace the first `cat` with it.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on @Anko's answer, you can use `tar` for multiple files:

```
ssh -q user@sourcehost 'cd /source/path; tar -czf - files...' | \
ssh -q user@desthost 'cd /dest/path; tar -xzf -'
```

Compressing is entirely optional - your data may not be very compressible or big enough to warrant the overhead. If your version of `tar` doesn't support the `-z` switch, pipe through `gzip -c` and `gzip -dc` respectively.

PS: Beware versions of `tar` that don't strip leading slashes on extraction (i.e., write to absolute pathnames if supplied).

Edit: `-e none` isn't needed with pipes, because a pseudo-terminal isn't allocated.

Comment: `ssh` has a `-C` flag to enable stream compression. According to the `man`-page, it uses the same algorithm as `gzip` though. The manual page also helpfully elucidates when to use it: "Compression is desirable on modem lines and other slow connections, but will only slow things down on fast networks."

Comment: @Anko, the problem with using `-C` here is that the local machine would have to uncompress and recompress the data.  Telling `tar` to do the compression means that the compressed data is passed straight through the pipe without any processing.