# Can not connect through sshfs because a wrong configuration at ~/.ssh/config file

Tags: ssh, fedora, sshfs, ssh-config

I am logged in in my local PC (Fedora 24) as `rperez`. From this PC I needed to connect to a remote server through `sshfs` so I generated a private/public key by running `ssh-keygen`. Using the following command I am able to connect to the server without any problem:

```
sshfs rperez@server_ip:/home/rperez -p 2051 ~/dev -o auto_cache,reconnect
```

Now I have two Github account: one to be used from work, one to be used from home for personal projects. I would like to connect to both using SSH so I have setup the first one using the generated key for `rperez` and again that works fine.

I am trying to setup the second one (the personal) on the same PC so I did run this command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "reynierpm@email.com"
```

I have created the file `~/.ssh/config` with the following content:

```
#rperez account
Host github.com-rperez
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

#reypm account
Host github.com-reypm
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_reynierpm

#Server
Host <server_ip>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

And this is where my problem started. Now running the following commands:

```
sshfs rperez@server_ip:/home/rperez -p 2051 ~/dev -o auto_cache,reconnect
sshfs rperez@server_ip:/home/rperez -p 2051 ~/dev -o auto_cache,reconnect,IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Return this error:

```
read: Connection reset by peer
```

I should add, regardless the current problem, that I am not able to connect either to any Github repository

What is wrong with this configuration?

I have take some ideas from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61567/sshfs-specify-key) but none is working for me. Also I am started from [this guide](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996) for setup the Github accounts

**Update:** verbose output

```
ssh -vvv -p 2051 rperez@server_ip
OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h-fips  3 May 2016
Bad owner or permissions on /home/rperez/.ssh/config
```

Comment: `ssh -vvv  rperez@server_ip`

Comment: @Jakuje thank, this put me on the right direction fixing the permissions by running `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config` make this work again. I'll not delete the post since maybe will be helpful for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the `ssh` in debug mode usually uncovers various problems. Usually permissions. In this case

```
Bad owner or permissions on /home/rperez/.ssh/config
```

means that the configuration file can not be writeable by others and therefore

```
chmod go-w /home/rperez/.ssh/config
```

should fix the problem for you.