# How do I use the ssh -i option to specify a ssh keypair to use for a ssh connection?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I need to connect to a SSH proxy server using a ssh keypair that I created specifically for it (not my default `id_rsa` keypair). I see from the `ssh` manual that there is a `-i` option that I can use to specify the new SSH keypair that I want to use.

I'm not sure how to actually invoke the `-i` option (I can't seem to find examples of the option in use). If this is the standard `ssh` command, how would I add the option? For the purpose of this question, assume that my new keypair is called `id_custom`.

```
ssh -N -D 8080 username@proxy.server.com
```

I tried adding `identityfile=/Users/username/.ssh/id_custom` to the end and it didn't work. (I saw this option in [ssh - How to specify key in SSHFS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61567/how-to-specify-key-in-sshfs)).

Comment: A colleague helped me out. It looks like this is the solution:

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_custom -N -D 8080 username@proxy.server.com`

Comment: You may find [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1367955/432690) useful.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the basic command,

```
ssh -i keyfile target_machine
```

and more specifically answering your question with the options and keyfile you presented there,

```
ssh -i /Users/username/.ssh/id_custom -N -D 8080 username@proxy.server.com
```

which is quite a lot to remember. I recommend using a `config` file to help you (user-specific one is `.ssh/config`, system-wide one is `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`) - `man ssh_config` for more info. Since you're using a proxy as you mention in your question with `-D` you can also use the `config` file to handle those details. Here some `config` options you could use in your `.ssh/config` file to allow you to have a simpler `ssh` command,

```
Host proxy.server.com
    User username
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_custom
    DynamicForward 8080
```

then the ssh command becomes easier (I don't know how to set the `-N` option in `.ssh/config` so leaving it here),

```
ssh -N proxy.server.com
```

Answer (score 1):

For AWS EC2 ssh, I use it like this:

```
ssh -i mykeypair.pem *user_name*@ec2-*publicDNS.zone*.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -i yourSSHkeyname username@hostname
```

https://medium.com/secttp/overthewire-bandit-level-13-dd14fd9aa3b2

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Your answer looks quite similar to the other ones, so you may want to edit it to explain how your approach is different from the answers already posted.